# merge control functions for checkboxes/ selects and inputs into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox, input

I've the following functions which enables/ disables a submit button in a form. All three are working fine separately but how merge them into one if it's possbile?

Now, if i select an option and a checkbox, the button is enabled, but if i deselect an option, the submit button is disabled again, but i want to let him enabled if one checkbox or option is select or one field is filled in.

```
$('#order input[type="text"]').change(function(){
if(($(this).val().length > 0))
$('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
else
$('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
});
            
$('#order :checkbox').change(function(){
            if($(this).not('.others').is(':checked'))
$('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
else
        $('#submit').prop('disabled',true);
    
    });
$('#order select').not('#sel_option_img').change(function(){
            if($(this).val() != '')
$('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
else
    $('#submit').prop('disabled',true);
    
    });

});
```

Sorry for my english, maybe not perfect.

Thanks in advance for helping.

**EDIT**

Link to the fiddle for better understanding:

http://jsfiddle.net/zVS3t/4/

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Is only one of the types of inputs required? So a user can select any valid dropdown option to enable the submit button, or check any checkbox to enable, or enter text into any of the text fields to.

Comment: @bdrx yes, only on type of input is required, but `('.others')` from checkboxes and `('#sel_option_img')` should be excluded from the whole code.  I've also tried [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/zVS3t/28/)  but it only works on the FIRST select box and on the FIRST text element and with ALL checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var orderText = $('#order input[type="text"]');
var orderCheck = $('#order :checkbox');
var orderSelect = $('#order select').not('#sel_option_img');

var enableOrDisableSubmit = function() {

    var textEntered = orderText.val().length > 0;
    var orderChecked = orderCheck.not('.others').is(':checked');
    var orderSelected = orderSelect.val() != '';

    if (textEntered && orderChecked && orderSelected)
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
    else
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);

};

orderText.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);

orderCheck.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);

orderSelect.change(enableOrDisableSubmit);
```

Note that we assign the jQuery references to variables so we can use them multiple times without traversing the DOM every time.

Comment: Not working :-(( If i do `alert(orderSelected);` and `alert(textEntered);` `alert(orderChecked);` i get always "false", while for the checkboxes it is fine.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/zVS3t/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/zVS3t/7/) : Link to your code. What's wrong with it?

Comment: This answer gets you almost what you want. You just need to change each && to || and it will work.

Comment: @bdrx It won't. I changed AND (&&) with OR (||) Try yourself [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/zVS3t/38/); you see that it will not work if you type something on the second,third, fourth,ecc, input field and it won't work on the second, third, fourth select box.

Comment: If you want to check multiple elements' values then check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zVS3t/43/  If this is what you want then I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at that:

**UPDATED:**

html change: `<option value="0">--please select--</option>`

function to check all inputs:

```
function checkinputs() {
    // if the select is defauld OR we have text inputs empty OR we dont have even one checkbox checked
    if( $("#order select").val() == "0" || $('#order input[type="text"]').filter(function(){return this.value == ""}).length || !$('#order input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') ) {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

simple `change` and `input` events of `"#order"`:

```
$( "#order" ).on('change input',function() {
    checkinputs();
});
```

### demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zVS3t/30/

Comment: Your code isn't working. I've tried [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/zVS3t/28/) but it only works on the FIRST select box and on the FIRST text element and with ALL checkboxes. Strange...

Comment: Maybe you have misunderstood my question: i need to get the submit button enabled if ONE of the options, checkboxes or textboxes is select/ filled in. Also in the select i need the value to be empty 'cause of the php file. Also, the html file is generated dynamically and can be very huge